# How to add to junction table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three tables `users`, `projects` and my junction table `user_projects`

I did this association on sequelize

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: User_Project });
```

[image]

This works (ignoring unneeded properties)

```
  const thomas = await User.create({
    username: "thomas",
    email: "thomas@email.com",
    password: "123456",
  });


  const projectOne = await Project.create({
    createdBy: thomas.id,
  })

  await thomas.addProject(projectOne)
```

However, Is there a way to do this with just the userId ?

For example, given id=10 I want to create a project as well as add that into the junction table

```
  // create the project
  const projectOne = await Project.create({
    createdBy: 10,
  })

  // how to add to junction table?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a defined junction table model then just use its `create` method:

```js
const projectOne = await Project.create({
    createdBy: thomas.id,
})
const userProjectRecord = await User_Project.create({
  userId:thomas.id,
  projectId: projectOne.id
})
```

Comment: And if you don't have a defined junction table model? I'm using the implicit junction table that sequelize creates

Comment: Well, it would be better to have the explicit junction table model especially if you plan to store additional props there.